# ClassCastException - Parcelable objects/Custom object

Tags: android, casting, classcastexception, parcelable

ive searched days here searching for a solution, but i cant find it.
I have a Activity who send an object through activities. But, when the "readParcelable" begins, after a few objects the CastExceptionError appears, ive debugged several times this code, tried to replace objects, comment objects, nothing works. Here the code:
All the classes implements Parcelable, writeToParcel, readFromParcel and CREATOR methods.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
       carregaDados();
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(ctx, Activity_VendaProduto.class);
       if (!logradouro.getText().toString().equals("")) {
           cliente.setEndereco(endereco); //nothing important here, just another object
           gerarVenda(); //who populates my "venda object with data"
           myIntent.putExtra("venda", venda);
       }
       startActivity(myIntent); 
    }
});
```

And here, the writeToParcel of this "Venda" object:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    dest.writeString(numeroContrato);
    dest.writeString(numeroProposta);
    dest.writeString(observacaoComplementar);
    dest.writeString(tipoVenda);
    dest.writeString(fidelidade);
    dest.writeString(hash);
    dest.writeString(oferta);

    dest.writeParcelable(visita, flags);
    dest.writeParcelable(midia, flags);
    dest.writeParcelable(tipoContratoVenda, flags);
    dest.writeParcelable(periodoInstalacao, flags);
    dest.writeParcelable(produtoAgrupamento, flags);
    dest.writeParcelable(formaPagamento, flags);
    dest.writeParcelable(vendaInternet, flags);

}
```

On this class, i have a constructor who calls the method: "readFromParcel" here the constructor:

```
private Venda(Parcel source) {
    readFromParcel(source);
}
```

And here is the readFromParcel method( ive checked several times the order of items on the write and this method)

```
 private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {

        numeroContrato = in.readString();
        numeroProposta = in.readString();
        observacaoComplementar = in.readString();
        tipoVenda = in.readString();
        fidelidade = in.readString();
        hash = in.readString();
        oferta = in.readString();

        visita =  in.readParcelable(Visita.class.getClassLoader());
        midia = in.readParcelable(Midia.class.getClassLoader());
        tipoContratoVenda = in.readParcelable(TipoContratoVenda.class.getClassLoader());
        periodoInstalacao = in.readParcelable(Periodo.class.getClassLoader());
        produtoAgrupamento = in.readParcelable(ProdutoAgrupamento.class.getClassLoader());
        formaPagamento = in.readParcelable(FormaPagamento.class.getClassLoader());
        vendaInternet =     in.readParcelable(VendaInternet.class.getClassLoader());
    }
```

All this readParcelable methods belongs to a custom object, and these objects class implements Parcelable and all of his methods as well.

here the LogCat error, occurs on this line:

```
            periodoInstalacao = in.readParcelable(Periodo.class.getClassLoader());
        produtoAgrupamento = in.readParcelable(ProdutoAgrupamento.class.getClassLoader());
```

Ive tried to comment , replace, but the error persists on the adjacent objects.

Logcat:

```
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{projetoTeste/projetoTeste.controle.Activity_VendaProduto}: java.lang.ClassCastException: projetoTeste.dto.Periodo cannot be cast to projetoTeste.dto.ProdutoAgrupamento
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: projetoTeste.dto.Periodo cannot be cast to projetoTeste.dto.ProdutoAgrupamento
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at projetoTeste.dto.Venda.readFromParcel(Venda.java:343)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at projetoTeste.dto.Venda.<init>(Venda.java:69)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at projetoTeste.dto.Venda.<init>(Venda.java:12)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at projetoTeste.dto.Venda$1.createFromParcel(Venda.java:349)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at projetoTeste.dto.Venda$1.createFromParcel(Venda.java:347)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:1992)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1854)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2094)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1158)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at projetoTeste.controle.Activity_VendaProduto.onCreate(Activity_VendaProduto.java:79)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
12:20:22.493    526 projetoTeste    ERROR   AndroidRuntime      ... 11 more
```

So, i came here to beg a light, ive tried and tried and cannot see where and why this error still occurs.

Thanks in advance!

--- UPDATE ---

Solved, ive followed the steps of the answer, fixed some conversions/write/read on Lists and Arrays and everythings looks to works fine now!
Thanks!

Comment: Try to replace all getClassLoader()  arguments to null, e.g. tipoContratoVenda = in.readParcelable(null); for all Parcelable objects.

Comment: what is the type of periodoInstalacao and produtoAgrupamento?

Comment: produtoAgrupamento is a ProdutoAgrupamento object
and periodoInstalacao a Periodo class (both implements Parcelable and methods, but inside ProdutoAgrupamento class i have a : "private ProdutoTipo[] tipoProdutoLista;" this list, dont know if is this guy causing this error, i dont think so, cause even when i comment the produtoAgrupamento, the cast error still occurs with the subjacent object on the read method

Comment: And replacing classLoader with null i get on the first (null) object: ERROR AndroidRuntime Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: projetoTeste.dto.Visita
..
and:
ERROR AndroidRuntime Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: projetoTeste.dto.Visita

Comment: Dont know if helps, but here my "Periodo" class: http://pastebin.com/2umQSxx4
And here my produtoAgrupamento class:
http://pastebin.com/LzYKN0rF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for proper code style, Add generic types to CREATOR to all Parcelable objects. For Periodo, it should be

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Periodo> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Periodo>() {
```

You don't need to do

```
if(tipoProdutoLista != null){
    for(int i=0; i < tipoProdutoLista.length;++i){
        parcelableTipoProduto[i] = (Parcelable) tipoProdutoLista[i];
    }
    dest.writeParcelableArray(parcelableTipoProduto, flags);
}
```

Just pass tipoProdutoLista as is, it is already Parcelable, and remove flags.

```
dest.writeParcelableArray(tipoProdutoLista, 0);
```

The error is, that you must not add the same flag that you got as writeToParcel argument when writing to Parcelable.

Replace flags when calling writeParcelable with zero

Was

```
dest.writeParcelable(visita, flags);
```

Should be

```
dest.writeParcelable(visita, 0);
```

Replace it in **all** places where you have *writeParcelable* call.

Comment: Im doing the changes, but ive used this for to the list because when i try to use writeParcelableArray i get:
`code`
method writeParcelableArray in class Parcel cannot be applied to given types;
  required: T[],int
  found: List<Produto>,int
  reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that argument type List<Produto> conforms to formal parameter type T[]
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Parcelable declared in method <T>writeParcelableArray(T[],int)`

Comment: And also cannot cast on:        produtoList =  in.readParcelableArray(Produto.class.getClassLoader());

cause of found Parcelable[] instead of Produto[], and casting with (Produto) didnt work.

Comment: Ive changed all classes for generics types on CREATOR, and changed flags for 0 on writeParcelable methods.
(Commented the parcelable list cause of the error on the previous comment)
Same lines/error: 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{projetoTeste/projetoTeste.controle.Activity_VendaProduto}: java.lang.ClassCastException: projetoTeste.dto.Periodo cannot be cast to projetoTeste.dto.ProdutoAgrupamento
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: projetoTeste.dto.Periodo cannot be cast to projetoTeste.dto.ProdutoAgrupamento`

Comment: Ive commented this "periodo" guy, this what the new error looks like:
`ERROR AndroidRuntime java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{projetoTeste/projetoTeste.controle.Activity_VendaProduto}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: `
And:
`ERROR AndroidRuntime Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling:`

Comment: And logcat point to this guy on produtoAgrupamento class:
`parcelableTipoProduto = in.readParcelableArray(ProdutoTipo.class.getClassLoader());`

Comment: Does Produto implements Parcelable?

Comment: Yes, Produto, ProdutoTipo, all these guys implements parcelables, and now with Generic CREATOR methods, let me know if i can provide any other code to clarify the problem

Comment: Thanks, you actually helped me with the creator comments when I tried to cast subclass to the class. overiding the creator function solve the cast error.